# Linux log in netwitness rsa

Tags: linux, logging

I am deploying netwitness 12.2 platform for testing. I have installed the agent endpoint on ubuntu but I don't know if it will retrieve the ubuntu host's event log to SIEM. If agent endpoint can get log then please help me config.

I have used syslog-ng to send logs to netwitness, however I want to find out if the linux agent endpoint in netwitness can be done to get logs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question seems more like a support question, and thusly is offtopic.  Try asking in Serverfault.